# What is the explanation of observing a constant data change in SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-view, viewrendering

When I study the SwiftUI Apprentice book of Kodeco, I come across the below code snippet.

```
struct CountdownView: View {
  let date: Date
  @Binding var timeRemaining: Int
  let size: Double

  var body: some View {
    Text("\(timeRemaining)")  // 5
      .font(.system(size: size, design: .rounded))
      .padding()
      .onChange(of: date) { _ in  // 6
        timeRemaining -= 1
      }
  }
}

struct TimerView: View {
  @State private var timeRemaining: Int = 3  // 1
  @Binding var timerDone: Bool  // 2
  let size: Double

  var body: some View {
    TimelineView(  // 3
      .animation(
        minimumInterval: 1.0,
        paused: timeRemaining <= 0)) { context in
          CountdownView(  // 4
            date: context.date,
            timeRemaining: $timeRemaining,
            size: size)
        }
        .onChange(of: timeRemaining) { _ in
          if timeRemaining < 1 {
            timerDone = true  // 7
          }
        }
  }
}

struct TimerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    TimerView(timerDone: .constant(false), size: 90)
  }
}
```

When I examine the code snippet, I firstly expected to be recreated `CountdownView`. But there would be no change on `date` property in that case. Then, I added `onAppear` modifier to `CountdownView` to detect the recreating of the view. As a result, it is created only once. I come up with a question to help me to understand the view rending mechanism of SwiftUI, on which I still work that although `date` property is a constant and does not use @`Binding` how is it possible to observe the change of a data that is declared as a constant in SwiftUI?

Comment: `onAppear` is not same as `onChange`

Comment: I have already written that I have added onAppear view modifier to detect if CountdownView is recreated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then, I added `onAppear` modifier to `CountdownView` to detect the recreating of the view. As a result, it is created only once.

While `onAppear` can indeed be used to detect the view being recreated. "Recreated" here does not mean "`CountdownView.init` got called". You can handwrite your own `CountdownView.init` to detect this.

`onAppear` gets called when the *actual thing on the screen* gets removed and recreated. This happens when, e.g. the identity of the view changes (learn more about identity in [Demystifying SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/)). Note that all you are doing in `body` is to provide a *description* of the view you are trying to create, and SwiftUI creates new views (this calls `onAppear`), or updates existing views (this doesn't call `onAppear`), all based on your descriptions. This is unlike in UIKit, where creating a `UILabel` with its initialiser directly creates something that can be shown on the screen.

In your code, you are calling `CountdownView.init` in a closure passed to `TimelineView`. SwiftUI runs this closure at appropriate times, and when it does so, it compares the `View` (i.e. the *description* of what views you want) it returns, with the `View` it returned last time.

SwiftUI sees that you used `onChange(of: date)` both in the previous description, and in this description, so it compares the `date`s from both descriptions, and finds that they are not equal. Therefore, it calls the closure you passed to `onChange`.

Of course, how it actually works is much more complicated, but this should be just enough to understand why you can `onChange` of a `let` constant. SwiftUI is comparing the previous version of your view's `body` with the new version's `body`.

Comment: In addition to this great answer: look into https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-find-which-data-change-is-causing-a-swiftui-view-to-update to experiment with and test the update cycle :)